# Calculate standard deviation between data in dataframes generated in a for cycle

Tags: python, pandas

I have a cycle that generates dataframes of the same size (96x96 or even , adds those dataframes on top of each other and then divides the result by the amount of iterations (count). This provides an average.
Now i need to calculate stdev between those generated dataframes. A cycle might generate as much as 365 DFs. I understand, that i need to remake the logic a bit, since to calculate stdev, one needs all the numbers of all dataframes.

What would be the best way to dot his? I was thinking about using MultiIndex, but since i am new to Python, i can't get my head around this.

So, here is a simple example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(5,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(zero_data, columns=[0,1,2,3,4])

for i in range(1,5):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 5)), columns=[0,1,2,3,4])
    zero_data = zero_data + df1
print(zero_data)
```

In this code, 5 dataframes are created and are added on top of each other. How can i calculate an std of those 5 dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of doing **'zero_data = zero_data + df1'**, i used **pd.concat([df1+df2])**, then i use **reset_index(**) and pass into **group_by(by='index')** after which i apply mean, std or whatever:

```
for i in range(0,5):
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 5)), columns=[0,1,2,3,4])
df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

df.reset_index().groupby(by='index').sum()

Turned out to be easier than i thought it would be :)